# Does the original string always stay unmodified?

Tags: javascript

```
 var name = 'naGeoExit';

 var name = name.substring(2,5);      
 console.log(name); //output: Geo
```

Is the first name variable and the second name variable are two different variables being allocated in the different parts of the memory or value of the original variable is being changed ?

Answer (score 4):

If they have the same name and are in the same scope then they're the same variable.

Answer (score 3):

At line 1, there is a string in memory containing "naGeoExit". There is a variable in scope, called `name` that points to it.

At the second line, there is a copy of the subsequence of the string in memory. The variable `name` now points to that. There is no reference to the original string object, so it is garbage collected at some point.

Using the `var` keyword means "create a variable in the current scope (rather than the global scope)". The current scope is a closure, for example a function definition (although it could also be the global scope if you are not in a function).

It is not a syntax error to use `var` twice, but its purpose is to create a new variable and you should only use it once per scope. Second time round will have no effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the original string is unmodified. In your example, though, it's immediately available for garbage collection.

Here's an example that shows that the string is unmodified more clearly:

```
var n1 = 'naGeoExit';

var n2 = n1.substring(2,5);      
console.log(n1); //output: naGeoExit
console.log(n2); //output: Geo
```

In your original code, you had only **one** variable called `name`, and you assigned the result of the `substring` operation to it, which is why the original string was immediately available for garbage collection. Re-declaring the same variable in the same scope has no effect. So the code:

```
var name = "foo";
var name = "bar";
```

...is exactly the same as:

```
var name = "foo";
name = "bar";
```

...and is, for that matter, exactly the same as:

```
var name;
name = "foo";
name = "bar";
```